# Оцените реализацию жизни Конвея

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Доброго дня всем. Оцените, пожалуйста, качество реализации и общего стиля кода (за исключением того, что все слито в один файл) игры "жизнь" Конвея. Пишу не так давно, поэтому важно мнение знающих людей. Заранее спасибо.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <style>
  body{
   margin: 0; 
   overflow: hidden;
      cursor: default;
  }
  input[type="button"]{
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
  }
  #start{
   right: 100px;
  }
  #stop{
   right: 50px;
  }
  #unitsValue{
   position: absolute;
   top: 40px;
   right: 50px;
   text-align: right;
  }
  #generation{
   position: absolute;
   top: 70px;
   right: 50px;
   text-align: right;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

 <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
 <input type="button" id="start" value="Старт">
 <input type="button" id="stop" value="Стоп" disabled>
 <input type="text" id="unitsValue">
 <input type="text" id="generation">

 <script type="text/javascript">
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#c7edfc";

  var width = canvas.width;
  var height = canvas.height;

  var step = 10; //unit size
  
  var unitsValue = document.getElementById('unitsValue');
  var generationPanel = document.getElementById('generation');
        
  function drawBackGround() {
   for (var i = step; i < width; i += step * 2) {
    ctx.strokeRect(i, 0, step, height);
    ctx.strokeRect(0, i, width, step);
   };
  };

  var notEmpty = 1;
  var generation = 1;
  var grid = [];
  function generateGrid(width, height) { //generating first generation grid
   ctx.fillStyle = "#8dcbe4";
   notEmpty = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < (height / step); i++){
    grid[i] = [];
    for (j = 0; j < (width / step); j++){
        grid[i][j] = Math.round(Math.random());
     if (grid[i][j] == 1) { notEmpty++ };
    };
   };

   unitsValue.value = notEmpty + " : units";
   generationPanel.value = generation + " : generation";
  };

  function drawUnits(grid) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#c7edfc";
      for (i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
              if (grid[i][j] == 1) {
                  ctx.fillRect(((j + 1) * step) - step, ((i + 1) * step) - step, step, step);
              };
          };
      };
  };

  function refresh() {
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      drawBackGround();
   drawUnits(grid);
  };

  canvas.onmousedown = function(c) { // manualy drawing
   ctx.strokeStyle = "#c7edfc";
   if (stopButton.disabled == true) {
    var m = Math.floor(c.pageX / step); 
    var n = Math.floor(c.pageY / step);
    console.log(m, n, grid[n][m]);  
    var chooseDestiny = grid[n][m];
    if (grid[n][m] == 1) { 
        grid[n][m] = 0; 
        ctx.clearRect(m * step, n * step, step, step);
        ctx.strokeRect(m * step, n * step, step, step);
       } else {
        grid[n][m] = 1;
        ctx.fillRect(m * step, n * step, step, step);
       };
    console.log(m, n, grid[n][m]);

       this.onmousemove = function(e) { // swipe
       var x = Math.floor(e.pageX / step);
        var y = Math.floor(e.pageY / step);
        if (x != m || y != n) {
         m = x; 
         n = y;
         if (chooseDestiny == 1) { 
          grid[y][x] = 0;
          ctx.clearRect(m * step, n *step, step, step);
          ctx.strokeRect(m * step, n *step, step, step);
         } else {
          grid[y][x] = 1;
          ctx.fillRect(m * step, n *step, step, step);
         };

     };
      };
      this.onmouseup = function(){ this.onmousemove = function(){}; }
   };
  };

  var newGrid = [];
  var oldGrid = [];
  function getNewGrid(grid) {
   notEmpty = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
    newGrid[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++){
     var neig = 0; 
     var tempGrid = [];

     if (grid[i][j] == 1) { notEmpty++ };
     
     if (i == 0) { // moore neighborhood
      for (var x = 0; x <= 1; x++) { 
       tempGrid[x] = [];
       for (var y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
        tempGrid[x][y+1] = grid[x][j+y];
       };
      };
     } else if (i == grid.length-1) {
      for (var x = -1; x <= 0; x++) { 
       tempGrid[x+1] = [];
       for (var y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
        tempGrid[x+1][y+1] = grid[i+x][j+y];
       };
      };
     } else {
      for (var x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
       tempGrid[x+1] = [];
       for (var y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
        tempGrid[x+1][y+1] = grid[i+x][j+y];
       };
      };
     };
     
     for (var n = 0; n < tempGrid.length; n++) { // neighbors value
      for (var m = 0; m < tempGrid[n].length; m++){
       if (tempGrid[n][m] == 1) { neig++ };
      };
     };
     if (grid[i][j] == 1) { neig -= 1 };

     if (grid[i][j] == 1 && (neig == 3 || neig == 2)) { // create new unnits
      newGrid[i][j] = 1;
     } else if (grid[i][j] == 0 && neig == 3) {
      newGrid[i][j] = 1;
     } else {
      newGrid[i][j] = 0;
     };
    };
   };
   unitsValue.value = notEmpty + " : units";
   generation++;
   generationPanel.value = generation + " : generation";
  };

  startButton = document.getElementById('start');
  stopButton = document.getElementById('stop');
  var cycleTimer;

  startButton.onclick = function () {
      refresh();
      cycleTimer = setTimeout(function cycle() {
          getNewGrid(grid);

          if (String(grid) == newGrid || String(newGrid) == oldGrid) { notEmpty = 0 };

          oldGrid = grid;
          grid = newGrid;
          newGrid = [];
          refresh();

          cycleTimer = setTimeout(cycle, 50);
      }, 50);

      setInterval(function () {
          if (notEmpty == 0) {
              ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
              ctx.font = "50px Arial"
              ctx.strokeText("LIFE IS OVER", width / 2, height / 2);
              clearInterval(cycleTimer);

              startButton.disabled = false;
              stopButton.disabled = true;
          };
      }, 100);

      startButton.disabled = true;
      stopButton.disabled = false;
  };

  stopButton.onclick = function () {
      clearInterval(cycleTimer);

      startButton.disabled = false;
      stopButton.disabled = true;
  };

  generateGrid(width, height);
  refresh();

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Такие вопросы не для SO. Вроде код рабочий, особо грубых ошибок нет (разве что `DOM Events 1` давно устарели).

Comment: @Other, вполне для RU.SO. См. [tag:инспекция-кода]

Comment: @Nofate, век живи - век учись, благодарю, буду знать.

Comment: Инспектировать каждую строку представленного JS-кода мне, наверно, "здоровья" не хватит, но мне, как минимум, не понравились 3 почти одинаковых цикла `for (var x = 0; x <= 1; x++) { tempGrid[x] = []; ...`. Имена переменных `n` и `m` не информативны, а `x` и `y` стоит использовать только для координат. Про отступы и переносы строк спорить не буду.